# How to load date from a file into SQL server table and also handle other characters in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, flat-file, ssis-2008

I am new to SSIS and I am trying to import a CSV file into a SQL server table using SSIS. The CSV file has a column for date and I have set the data type as `DT_DATE`. The format of the date `MM/dd/yyyy`. However, for months and dates less than 10, it does not have the leading zeroes, i.e., `March 7, 2012` is in the file `3/7/2012`. The rows that do not have the date values has a - character. Can someone help me, how do load this data into SQL server. I assume the date of `3/7/2012` will be loaded into the table without issues. However, I want to handle the dashes and load them as `NULL` into the SQL server. Can I use a derived column? If the value is -, set it to `NULL`, other populate the date value as it is. Is this correct?

I tried the below code and I am getting some error message.

```
ISNULL([Last Contacted Date]) || (DT_WSTR,1)[Last Contacted Date] == "-" || (DT_WSTR,0)[Last Contacted Date] == "" ? NULL(DT_DATE) : [Last Contacted Date]
```

For the Derived Last Contacted Date column, I had set the Error and Truncation properties to "Ignore failure" and the job ran fine.

However, when I run the SSIS job, the data is getting loaded into the SQL server table, but the last contacted date on ALL records in SQL server table is NULL. The file has several rows where the value is a valid date.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

In the Flat File Connection Manager, set the column type to `DT_WSTR` with an appropriate length, then use a Derived Column with the following expression:

```
REPLACENULL([Last Contacted Date],"") == "" ? NULL(DT_DATE) :
(DT_DATE)(RIGHT("0" +  [Last Contacted Date], FINDSTRING( [Last Contacted Date], "/", 1 ) - 1) 
+ "/" + 
RIGHT("0" + SUBSTRING([Last Contacted Date], FINDSTRING( [Last Contacted Date], "/", 1 ) +1, FINDSTRING( [Last Contacted Date], "/", 2 ) - FINDSTRING( [Last Contacted Date], "/", 1 ) - 1), 2)
+ "/" + 
RIGHT([Last Contacted Date],4))
```